# Where can I find the absolute newest version of ath10k and download it?

Tags: wireless

I have linux kernal 4.3.0-040300-generic right now and my wireless has stopped working.

I need to find the newest version of ath10k and download it but I don't know where it is. Can someone help me find it and give link or instructions to download?

https://www.searx.me/?q=4.3.0-040300-generic%20ath10k&categories=general

Related information:

```
fringe@fringe-Alienware-17-R2 ~ $ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for fringe: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 34:e6:d7:69:62:2a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.2.49 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f7400000-f743ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f6800000-f69fffff

> Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology 
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0528 Alienware Corporation 
> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:6708 Microdia 
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1525]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5227] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

You may just need firmware to be able to use the device

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
```

Reboot, if it doesn't work, please edit your question to include `dmesg | grep ath` as a bug report suggests a different firmware file might be needed